# Observables expressed by the lesser Green's function $\tilde{\mathcal{G}}^{<}(k, E)$

Tags: greens-functions, observables, non-equilibrium

I am reading the paper [PRB 106, 035102 (2022)](https://doi.org/10.1103/PhysRevB.106.035102). In the supplementary materials, it says, within the Green’s function formalism, the thermal and quantum average of an observable θ is expressed as,

$$\langle\theta\rangle=-\mathrm{i} \int \frac{\mathrm{d} k}{(2 \pi)^d} \int \frac{\mathrm{d} E}{2 \pi} \operatorname{Tr}\left\{\theta \tilde{\mathcal{G}}^{<}(k, E)\right\}.$$

Here $\theta$ can be various responses, such as charge current, spin current, or heat flux. $\tilde{\mathcal{G}}^{<}(k, E)$ is the lesser Green's function, and plays the role of "energy resolved" distribution function.

I want to know how to derived the equation. If possible, recommend some textbooks with detail derivation.